# Get ObjectId from BsonValue with Java mongodb client

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using mongodb-driver-sync as my Java driver.

I have an Author class.

```
public class Author {
  String name;
  ObjectId id;

// getters setters constructors
}
```

I am inserting into my Mongo collection with the following code

```
MongoCollection<Author> collection = database.getCollection("authors", Author.class)

Author author = new Author();
author.setName("Apple");

InsertOneResult result = collection.insertOne(author)

// This fails because result.getInsertedId returns a BsonValue instead of ObjectId
author.setId(result.getInsertedId())

return author;
```

I am trying to get setId() to work, but it is failing because .getInsertedId() returns a BsonValue. Is there a way to convet BsonValue to ObjectId?

I have tried using ObjectMapper but I am still exploring.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the built-in method from BsonValue:

```
result.getInsertedId().asObjectId().getValue();
```

That should be enough.